# schur index in GAP

Tags: gap, magma-cas

What is the command for the Schur index in GAP? Let $χ$ be an irreducible (complex) character of a finite group, $G$. The Schur index $m_K(χ)$ of $χ$ over the field $K$ is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $m_χ$ is afforded by a representation over the field $K(χ)$. The most interesting case is $K=\mathbb{Q}$. Given the character table, or only the particular character one is interested in, one can usually derive bounds for $m(χ)=m_\mathbb{Q}(χ)$.

In MAGMA, this could be done as follows (see [here](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/997#11041)):

```
T:=CharacterTable(Group);
SchurIndex(T[number of row of T]);
```

Answer (score 4):

In GAP, this functionality had been recently implemented by [Allen Herman](http://www.math.uregina.ca/~aherman/) in the package [Wedderga](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/wedderga.html) (Wedderburn Decomposition of Group Algebras), starting from version 4.6. To use it, you need to load the package first with `LoadPackage("wedderga");`.

The two functions are `SchurIndex( A )` and `SchurIndexByCharacter( F, G, n )`. The first of these returns the Schur index of the simple algebra `A`. The second returns the Schur index of the simple component of the group ring `FG` corresponding to the irreducible character `Irr(G)[n]` of `G`.

See Wedderga manual in your GAP installation or find in online [here](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/pkg/wedderga/doc/chap7.html) for the full documentation.

Just two illustrative examples from the Wedderga manual are given below:

```
gap> LoadPackage("wedderga");
...
true

gap> G:=SmallGroup(63,1);  
<pc group of size 63 with 3 generators>
gap> R:=GroupRing(Rationals,G);
<algebra-with-one over Rationals, with 3 generators>
gap> W:=WedderburnDecompositionInfo(R);
[ [ 1, Rationals ], [ 1, CF(3) ], [ 1, CF(9) ], 
  [ 1, NF(7,[ 1, 2, 4 ]), 7, [ 3, 2, 0 ] ], 
  [ 1, NF(21,[ 1, 4, 16 ]), 21, [ 3, 4, 7 ] ] ]
gap> SchurIndex(W[5]);
3

gap> G:=SmallGroup(40,1);              
<pc group of size 40 with 4 generators>
gap> Size(Irr(G));                          
16
gap> SchurIndexByCharacter(GaussianRationals,G,16);
2
gap> SchurIndexByCharacter(CF(5),G,16);         
1
```