Can every representation of a perfect finite group be realized with matrices over the field generated by the character values?
Let $ G $ be perfect finite group and let $ \chi $ be an irreducible complex character of $ G $ of degree $ n $. Let $ K $ be the field generated by the character values of $ \chi $. Does there always exist some representation $ \pi: G \to GL(n,K) $ with character $ \chi $?
In other words can any representation of a perfect finite group be realized with matrices over the field generated by the character values?
In my experience this seems to be true for some small perfect groups like $ A_5, SL(2,5), GL(3,2), SL(2,7) $.

It's not true for the faithful $6$-dimensional irreducible representation of ${\rm SL}(2,5)$. It's character values are integers, but the representation cannot be realized over the rationals.

There are also simple examples with nontrivial Schur Index. The smallest is the $6$-dimensional representation of ${\rm PSU}(3,3)$.

@DerekHolt Oh those are both great counterexamples. How do you know that they cannot be realized over the rationals? I noticed that both of these counterexamples have integer valued characters and have Frobenius-Schur indicator $ -1 $, is that information relevant?

Irreducible complex characters $\chi$ of a finite group have a Schur Index $m(\chi)$. If the character field of the representation is $K={\mathbb Q}(\chi)$, then $m(\chi)$ is the smallest degree $|L:K|$ of a field $L$ over which the representation can be realized. So if the Schur Index is greater than $1$ then the representation cannot be realized over $K$.
There are many examples of perfect groups with characters with Schur Index greater than $1$. They exist for ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ for all odd primes $q$ and, as I said in a comment, there are examples with simple groups, such as the $6$-dimensional character of ${\rm PSU}(3,3)$. Schur Indexes (Indices?) can be calculated in Magma, for example.
This situation arises from endomorphism rings that are non-commutative division algebras. S by Wedderburn's Theorem that finite division rings are fields the Schur Index over a finite field is always $1$. So over finite fields all representations of finite groups can be written over their (Brauer) character rings.

Ah I see and here is how to do it in GAP https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814823/schur-index-in-gap
